# overrides and linked collections, saving problem

Tags: linked-data, saving, library-overrides

I have a couple questions that are related:

a.  I have a problem saving objects I've modified from linked collections.  They sometimes disappear as soon as I save the file I'm working on.  So far, the only thing that prevents this is copying the object and dragging it out of the collection.

If anyone has had a similar problem let me know if you were able to solve it.

b. I am just learning about the "make library override" function, and I am just wondering if it is relevant to my problem.

Can someone explain the theory behind the library override function?

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what exactly happens, at what time ,and after which action ? From my understanding, it could simply be you modified the origin of the linked object in the library file, and then it got displaced off screen in your working file

Comment: I have downloaded some tutorials on animation.  The characters are part of a linked library.  I animate the character, save the file, and the rig disappears.

Comment: The tutorials mention the "make library override" function for certain objects, and I have tried to use it.  But this is not when the problem occurs.  As I said, it only occurs after I save the file.

Comment: Do you mean the object disappears from the work file, it is nowhere to be found in the hierarchy ? And yes, library overrides are the preferred way for working with linked libraries since they offer more functionality than the old proxy system. Overrides let the user change properties on linked objects, while retaining a link to all other properties

Comment: In reference to the glitch, yes, the objects are disappearing from the hierarchy completely on Save.

Comment: This is weird, it shouldn't happen. Consider reporting this as a bug with Help > Report a bug inside blender

Comment: Same happens here. I do a library override to a material of a linked object. When reloading the changed file, my overrides are completely gone and the origin version appears.
Even if I make the overriden materials local, the same happen: All my changes disappear. Any ideas?